# Write a query to print last date of the year and the input will be of any date

Tags: sql, oracle

Need to write a query to return last date of the year. Input can be any date... I wrote

```sql
SELECT LPAD(SUBSTR('11/01/2001',-4),10,'31/12/') FROM DUAL.
```

Is this correct or any other way to write the query....

Comment: tag with appropriate DBMS

Comment: Is your input "date" a DATE (datatype = date) or a STRING representation of a date?  Do you need to return a DATE or a STRING representation of a date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC (date'2001-01-11' ,'YEAR'),12)-1 FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like,

```
-- First Day of Current Year:
select trunc(sysdate,'year') from dual;

-- Last Day of Current Year:
select add_months(trunc(sysdate,'year'),12)-1 
  from dual;
  
-- last day for any given date
with date_field
as
(select date'2001-01-11' input from dual)
select add_months(trunc(input,'year'),12)-1 
  from date_field;
```

Comment: @Ragu pathi: I am not complaining but  may I know what's wrong with my answer ?